# Changing single value state to object state

Tags: reactjs

I have this line to set state.

```
const [selectedGames, setSelectedGames] = useState('');
```

However, I want to instead have a state object with multiple properties. e.g. name, date etc. How do I modify that line to allow this and then also how do I set say the name property of the state?

Answer (score 1):

Set an object for your state

```
const [selectedGames, setSelectedGames] = useState({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
});
```

Use spread operator for the keys and update the property you want with

```
setSelectedGames({...selectedGames, c: 4})
```

> Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a list of some kind.

Read more about [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Well explained, thank you. What happens if you omit the `...selectedGames` part? Does it basically set those other object properties to null or leave them alone?

Comment: `spread` operator make a copy of all the properties your object has. @Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can create the state like

const [selectedGames,setSelectedGames] = useState({key:value}

create as many key:value as you like.

And to set Any key a value use the setSelectedGames() method
like:

```
 setSelectedGames({...selectedGames,key:newValue})
```

...selectGames is all The states you don't want to change or to keep as is